# ImageMagick convert command delegate error

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, freetype

While excuting below convert command on linux getting delegate error for font .

```
convert -font /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n021003l.pfb -pointsize 48 -size 
400 caption:ABC text.png
```

convert: delegate library support not built-in '/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n021003l.pfb' (Freetype) @ warning/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1818.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format PNG error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.
convert: delegate library support not built-in '/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n021003l.pfb' (Freetype) @ warning/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1818.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.
convert: no images defined `text.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3254.

Below is the output when I run the command "convert -list configure"

```
Path: /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.6//config-Q16HDRI/configure.xml

Name           Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CC             gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu99
CFLAGS         -I/usr/include/libxml2      -fopenmp -g -O2 -Wall -mtune=core-
avx-i -fexceptions -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
CODER_PATH     /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.6/modules-Q16HDRI/coders
CONFIGURE      ./configure 
CONFIGURE_PATH /usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/
COPYRIGHT      Copyright (C) 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
CPPFLAGS       -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7
CXX            g++
CXXFLAGS       -g -O2 -pthread
DEFS           -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
DELEGATES      mpeg ps x xml zlib
DISTCHECK_CONFIG_FLAGS  --disable-deprecated  --with-quantum-depth=16  --with-jemalloc=no  --with-umem=no  --with-autotrace=no  --with-gslib=no  --with-fontpath=  --with-rsvg=no  --with-perl=no 
DOCUMENTATION_PATH /usr/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-7
EXEC-PREFIX    /usr/local
EXECUTABLE_PATH /usr/local/bin
FEATURES       DPC HDRI Cipher OpenMP
FILTER_PATH    /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.6/modules-Q16HDRI/filters
GIT_REVISION   11994
HOST           x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
INCLUDE_PATH   /usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7
LDFLAGS        -L/usr/local/lib  
LIB_VERSION    0x706
LIB_VERSION_NUMBER 7,0,6,0
LIBRARY_PATH   /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.6
LIBS                              -lXext    -lX11        -lxml2    -lz    -lm -lgomp    
NAME           ImageMagick
PCFLAGS        -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -
DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
PREFIX         /usr/local
QuantumDepth   16
RELEASE_DATE   2017-07-17
SHARE_PATH     /usr/local/share/ImageMagick-7
SHAREARCH_PATH /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.6/config-Q16HDRI
TARGET_CPU     x86_64
TARGET_OS      linux-gnu
TARGET_VENDOR  unknown
VERSION        7.0.6
WEBSITE        http://www.imagemagick.org

Path: [built-in]

Name           Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FEATURES       OpenMP 
NAME           ImageMagick
QuantumDepth   16'
```

When tried to run the "identify -list font" command it has support for the font which is used in convert command here.

```
Font: Times-Roman
family: Times
style: Normal
stretch: Normal
weight: 400
glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n021003l.pfb
```

Any help appreciated . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the font is a **freetype** one and you have not got the `freetype` delegate installed - it is not listed under `DELEGATES` in your `identify -list configure` or if you run `identify -version`. You need to install it.